# Mismatch EPSG4326 tiles and (0, 0) origin point

Tags: javascript, leaflet, coordinates

I am currently trying to create a tile map in Leaflet and I want to be able to sync real life EPSG4326 coordinates in the map but I can't change the location of the map.

In this picture you guys can see where is (0,0) and not in the middle of the map:

[image: in this picture you guys can see where is (0,0) and not in the middle of the map]

and this is my code:

````
  var mapMaxZoom = 6
  var mapMinZoom = 0

  var mymap = L.map('mapid', {crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326}).setView([0,0], mapMaxZoom);

L.tileLayer('./tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
  noWrap: true,
  minZoom: mapMinZoom,
  maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
  tms: true,
}).addTo(mymap);

L.marker([0,0]).addTo(mymap)
.bindPopup('A popup.')
.openPopup();

console.log("map crs: " + mymap.options.crs.code)

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

function onMapClick(e) {
    alert("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng);
}```
````

Comment: What are the coordinates of the shown tiles? Looks strange that you do not have a full Earth.

Comment: @ghybs i dont have full earth because its all local, i dont use the leaflet servers, my map is tms(tile map server) and i need to know how to set my tiles coordinates so they will be the same as google earth coordinates, meaning that (34,34) in google earth will be the same place in my map

Comment: Side note: Leaflet is just the library, it does not serve tiles.

Comment: You can inspect browser network requests to see what tiles are fetched from another tile source

Comment: @ghybs i know but instead of calling opensteetmap server or somthing i call my tiles on my server, i just want to know  how can i set my tiles coordinates and not leaflet

Comment: @ghybs you can see how im fetching the tile in the code i attached, you can see that im calling the tiles from my root diractory

Comment: Sounds like you may not understand how your tiles should be named. The above code has nothing particularly wrong, but if your tiles are named incorrectly, there is nothing we can help you with without further details. As previously said, a very easy comparison can already be done with another similar tile source.

Comment: @ghybs so your telling me there isnt an easy way to set the the middle point to my desire coordinates?

Comment: There are several ways, like modifying the CRS, modifying tile coordinates on the fly, or more simply having your tile coordinates comply with the expected convention.